# Tight VNC for remote desktop view

Tags: remote-desktop

I have downloaded  TightVNC Remote Desktop View form following link

http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php

Which is running ok on local LAN but it is not able to connect to remote PC in other network. I want to modify this code so that it can connect to remote PC in other network. I am new to socket programming; I have studied about NAT Traversal, UDP and TCP Hole Punching. Can some one guide me in achieving the above task? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ravi Shankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to configure port forwarding on the router in the remote network, no programming required. See the section in the TightVNC FAQ, [How would I connect from the Internet to a machine in the internal network which is behind a router?](http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php#portfwd)

Comment: Hi John T,
Thanks for you pormpt reply. We don't have router in our netwrok. All PC are connected through a switch.

Comment: I'm talking about the remote PC in the other network. Is it behind a router?

Comment: Hi John T, in our network all PC are connected to a DLINK ethernet switch, which is connected to a modem. I have also tried all the options in link which you have provided. I have added a virtual service with the said port 5800 but still I am not able to connect from remote pc in other network.

Comment: Hi John T, Both the network are configured in the same manner.

Comment: Check the firewall on the remote PC.